# C input and return

Tags: c, input, return

I am trying to work on a employee management system that takes employee information as input and prints the output accordingly.

Structure:

```
struct employee
{
    char empId[10];
    char name[20];
    char empType[10];
    int dd, mm, yyyy;
};
```

Program to check if the string contains only integers:

```
void checkValidId(char *id)
{
    int count = 0, i;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(id); i++)
    {
        if(id[i] >= '0' && id[i] <= '9')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count == strlen(id))
        // continue executing next statements of input() function
    else
        // take the empId input again
}
```

Function to take input:

```
struct employee input()
{
    struct employee e;

    printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
    scanf("%s", &e.empId); 
    checkValidId(e.empId);

    // next statements ....
}
```

Here I am trying to check if the string input that is empId contains only integers which is done by checkValidId(). If yes then the program continues executing next statements. Else I want to take the input empId again. How to do it.

Requesting help!

Thanks!

Comment: `scanf("%s", &e.empId); ` ---> Does the compiler emit a warning for this?

Comment: Instead of `id[i] >= '0' && id[i] <= '9'` use `isdigit(id[i])`.

Comment: It's good that you're trying to validate input. `scanf()` might not be the best option for reading strings. Perhaps switch to `fgets()`, and then parse the string with ```strtol``` or so? You will find many such examples on SO.

Comment: Change `checkisvalidid` to return a `bool`. Loop until the function returns `true`.

Comment: Note that `scanf()` would happily continue reading from `stdin` and overflow the buffer. Specify a field-width. `scanf ("%9s", e.empId);`

Comment: And again, we see `strlen` being called over and over and over again for no reason.   Bad code. Call it *once*.  It's just common sense.  Don't make your code do unnecessary work.

Comment: "Else I want to take the input empId again. How to do it." With a loop. Are you familiar with loops?

Answer (score 2):

Include the header [`<ctype.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), and use [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) to test if a character is in the set `'0'` ... `'9'`.

Include the header [`<stdbool.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types), and change the signature of `checkValidId` to

```
bool checkValidId(const char *id)
```

in order to indicate a result to the calling function.

In `checkValidId`, loop through each character of the string. If the current character is not a digit, immediately return `false` from the function. If the loop finishes, all the characters must be digits, so you can then return `true`.

Note that there is no reason to call `strlen` here. Simply loop until the current character is the null-terminating byte.

---

`&e.empId` is of type `char (*)[10]`, that is a *pointer-to-array-of-10-char*. The [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) specifier `"%s"` expects the type `char *`, or `pointer-to-char`. An array will *decay* to a pointer to its first element when passed to a function, so the the 'correct' way to call `scanf` here is `scanf("%s", e.empId);`.

That said, you must check that the return value of `scanf` is the *expected number of conversions*, otherwise you will be operating on indeterminate data.

Additionally, an unbound `"%s"` is [as dangerous as the `gets` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965), as it does not know when to stop reading data, and will easily overflow the provided buffer. You must provide a *maximum field width* to prevent `scanf` from reading too many characters. This should be at most the size of your buffer minus 1, leaving room for the null-terminating byte.

An example of using `scanf` safely:

```
if (1 != scanf("%9s", e.empId)) {
    /* handle input stream error */
}
```

Note that when `scanf` fails to perform a conversion, the problem data is left in the stream. Recovering from bad input with `scanf` is very hard, and for that reason a line-based approach to user input is generally advised. This can be accomplished with [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

If there is room in the buffer, `fgets` includes the newline character when read. See [Removing trailing newline character from `fgets()` input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2505965) for an example usage of [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn), which can also be used as a way to get the length of the input.

---

To repeatedly ask the user for input, use an infinite loop. Only `break` from the loop when the user correctly enters the requested data, or a critical error occurs.

Here is an example program, using the methods discussed:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee {
    char empId[10];
    /* ... */
};

bool checkValidId(const char *id)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; id[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (!isdigit((unsigned char) id[i]))
            return false;

    return true;
}

bool getEmployee(struct employee *e, FILE *stream)
{
    char buffer[256];

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter employee ID: ");

        if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stream))
            return false;

        size_t length = strcspn(buffer, "\r\n");
        /* remove the newline */
        buffer[length] = '\0';

        if (!length)
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid ID. Zero length.\n");
        else if (length >= sizeof e->empId)
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid ID. Too long.\n");
        else if (!checkValidId(buffer))
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid ID. Contains non-digit character(s).\n");
        else {
            strcpy(e->empId, buffer);
            break;
        }

        puts("Try again.");
    }

    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct employee emp;

    if (!getEmployee(&emp, stdin))
        return 1;

    printf("ID: <%s>\n", emp.empId);
}
```

Interacting with this program:

```
Enter employee ID: foobar
Invalid ID. Contains non-digit character(s).
Try again.
Enter employee ID: 
Invalid ID. Zero length.
Try again.
Enter employee ID: 1234567890
Invalid ID. Too long.
Try again.
Enter employee ID: 42
ID: <42>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `checkValidId` should return `int` so it can tell the caller whether the `id` is valid [or not].
2. A caller (e.g. `input`) should loop if the return value of `checkValidId` indicates a bad id.
3. No need to use `strlen` at all.
4. No need to compare lengths. A simpler algorithm can be used.
5. We can just stop the loop if an invalid char is detected

Here is the refactored code:

```
struct employee {
    char empId[10];
    char name[20];
    char empType[10];
    int dd, mm, yyyy;
};

// Program to check if the string contains only integers:
// RETURNS: 1=input valid, 0=retry
int
checkValidId(char *id)
{
    int valid = 0;

    for (int i = 0; id[i] != 0; i++) {
        valid = (id[i] >= '0') && (id[i] <= '9');
        if (! valid)
            break;
    }

    return valid;
}

// Function to take input:
struct employee
input(void)
{
    struct employee e;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
        scanf("%s", &e.empId);
        if (checkValidId(e.empId))
            break;
    }

    // next statements ....
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &e.empId);` is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).